# How to add Horizontal Scrolling Card in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am learning Flutter recently for my school project and I am trying to add widget to like this

[image]

I have made searchs on the internet and what i found is using ListViewScrollView widget horizontally. But ListViewScrollView widget is 3D and I only need to show one element on the screen with **swiping the other**. Is there any built-in widget. If not exist how can i add these little dots at the below in my custom widget with a box.

Comment: I haven't found a way to create that effect easily with any built-in widget. But I happily took "Carousel Slider" package in use: https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider

Comment: Thanks man I don't even know this widget has particular name. It is exactly what I looking for.